# Why are not Mate, Cinnamon and Pantheon available in default Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: cinnamon, mate, pantheon

Cinnamon and Mate are available in Fedora. Why aren't they present in official Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cinnamon` is available in the default repositories for 13.04

`mate-desktop-environment` is available from it's own repository with packages for 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04
To add the mate repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repo.mate-desktop.org/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://mirror1.mate-desktop.org/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main"
```

`pantheon` is considered an unstable environment for the (still in beta) elementary OS

Info from the elementary PPA page [here](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/daily):

> ATTENTION!
>   Do NOT install this PPA if you want a tested running system, this PPA contains the newest and most unstable development of elementary, it's useful only if you are a developer and are not afraid to encounter CRITICAL BUGS.

The [stable elementary PPA](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/stable) contains only packages for precise

Comment: This answers the question about the Cinnamon part, but it doesn't for the Mate part.

Comment: Some developers may prefer to have the packages hosted at their own website (like for mate) and as an official source, it's more trustworthy than a PPA on launchpad

Comment: @minerz029 Mate repo is very slow. It took about an hour for me to install it. My connection speed is 512 kbps.

Comment: @apanda Added info about mate mirrors to my answer which may be faster